# How to see which users upvoted a question?

Tags: support, api, documentation

I assume this information is tracked, since StackOverflow shows me the questions I have upvoted (when going to their question page, I can undo the upvote). I couldn't find any api call that gives this information, and I couldn't find it in the creative commons data dump.

I assume this is not shown for "security" purposes (i.e. this kind of information is not supposed to be advertised), but I figured I'd make sure that I wasn't just missing something.

Is there a way to get that information? Or is it (purposefully) not shown?

Thanks

Answer (score 17):

Purposefully not shown.

The potential for abuse is *way* too high.